# My progress bar is disappearing

Tags: vb.net

My progressbar is disappearing as soon as I start running any code. Why's that?
That's really strange.

```
Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click

    StartThinking()

    For Each z In ListBox1.Items
        Dim u = FindIPAddress(z)
        ListBox2.Items.Add(If(IsNothing(u), "Not found!", u))
    Next

    StopThinking()

End Sub

Sub StartThinking()
    Cursor = Cursors.WaitCursor
    ProgressBar1.Minimum = 0
    ProgressBar1.Style = ProgressBarStyle.Marquee
End Sub

Sub StopThinking()
    ProgressBar1.Minimum = ProgressBar1.Maximum
    ProgressBar1.Style = ProgressBarStyle.Blocks
    Cursor = Cursors.Arrow
End Sub
```

Comment: Changing the Style property has drastic side-effects, it requires the native control window to be re-created.  You never give it a chance to repaint, your UI thread is stuck in FindIPAddress().  The cursor doesn't change either.  Use a BackgroundWorker to execute code that takes a while and makes you UI go catatonic.

Comment: You could presumably call the `Refresh` method of your `ProgressBar` to make it repaint after changing the `Style` but you're still not going to see any animation because, as Hans Passant says, your UI thread is too busy doing your work to make the UI responsive.  Always keep in mind that one thread can only do one thing at a time.  If you ever want your UI to be responsive while you're doing other work then that other work must be done on another thread.  A `BackgroundWorker` is one of the easiest way to achieve that in a GUI app.